# Constrains on imageView doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'd like to optimize my app for the 3,5 inch display. The imageView is at the bottom of the view at the 4 inch display. But if I add constrains on my imageView it's not rescaled and I don't see the whole imageView at the 3,5 inch display.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
            // iPhone retina-4 inch
        } else{

            [self.scrollViewImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 213, 320, 267)];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How about adding some code?

Comment: Can you give me an exaple please?

Comment: I updated the question with some code which isn't working.

Comment: "Constraints" implies auto layout. If you're using auto layout, you can't set the frames of views. You must adjust constraints themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the layout constraints within the interface builder.

Using auto-layout on storyboard or xib you need to add at least 4 constraints per object. I've added a picture of how to add constraints to a UIImageView object which is close to the bottom of the view

[image]

Select the UIImageVIew object on the view then press the constraints icon like below. Within this constraint options view here I've added a constraint fixing the distance to the object to its left (in this case is the side of the view) and a constraint fixing to the bottom of the view. Highlighting the spring icons (turning orange colour) means they have been selected. I also have the height and width of the UIImageView object constraints selected here as I also want these properties not to change (get squashed).

Here is a link to an auto-layout tutorial.

[beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks! Another question: Is it posible to resize the view from 320x320 to 250x250?